# Wait for a server response (and check value) in Protractor test

Tags: angularjs, server, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have a page in my site that is making a request to the server and then using the result to populate a table.

How can I write an e2e test for this? I am having trouble working out how to wait for the server response, and how I would get the data from the response, so I can then check it against the table contents.

Here is a simplified example of my Angular controller:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myCtrl", function(MyService) {

   MyService.getData()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        });
});
```

Then the html page is looping over the items in $scope.data to populate the table.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you don't have to worry about this since `protractor` knows when angular is ready to go and the page is loaded. In other words, [it syncs with Angular itself](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/):

> You no longer need to add waits and sleeps to your test. Protractor can automatically execute the next step in your test the moment the
>   webpage finishes pending tasks, so you don’t have to worry about
>   waiting for your test and webpage to sync.

In some cases though, you need to explicitly wait for some expected condition to be satisfied via [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait). For instance, you may wait until a particular element becomes present:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.css("#myid"));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 10000);
```

There is a large set of [built-in Expected Conditions](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions), check it out.

What exactly to wait for in your case, depends on what is happening in the browser when the browser receives that server response - may be there is some table appearing, or there are additional table rows added to an existing table etc.

Comment: What if we didn't get response in 10 seconds?